# Web scraping table elements - Uncaught Error

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to scrape data from a website using Simple htm dom and PHP

Website:
http://portal.chmi.cz/aktualni-situace/aktualni-stav-pocasi/ceska-republika/stanice/profesionalni-stanice/tabulky/teplota

But My code is not working, I got a fatal error.
Can anyone help me?

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on array
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_dom\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_dom\index.php on line 20

My code:

```
<?php
      include('simple_html_dom.php');

      $html = file_get_html('http://portal.chmi.cz/aktualni-situace/aktualni-stav-pocasi/ceska-republika/stanice/profesionalni-stanice/tabulky/teplota',false);

      $table = $html->find('table');
      $Data = array();

      foreach($table->find('tr[class=portlet-table-alternate]') as $row) {

          $rowData = array();

              foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {

                  $rowData[] = $cell->innertext;
                  }

          $Data[] = $rowData;
      }
      print_r($Data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what's the problem. You get an `array` as a response of the `file_get_html` `function`. In the next line, when you call

```
$table = $html->find('table');
```

you are trying to call the `find` method of your `array`, which is violating the rules of PHP. You will need to find out why you get an `array`, what its contents are. Intuitively, I think you get an `array` where one of the items (possibly having an index of 0) is containing the item you seek. You will need therefore to investigate your `array`. If it's an error, then you will make a successful step forward, understanding the nature of your problem. If it's a result with a useful attribute, then you will be able to use that. For more reference, the implementation of `file_get_html`:

```
/**
 * All of the Defines for the classes below.
 * @author S.C. Chen <me578022@gmail.com>
 */
define('HDOM_TYPE_ELEMENT', 1);
define('HDOM_TYPE_COMMENT', 2);
define('HDOM_TYPE_TEXT',    3);
define('HDOM_TYPE_ENDTAG',  4);
define('HDOM_TYPE_ROOT',    5);
define('HDOM_TYPE_UNKNOWN', 6);
define('HDOM_QUOTE_DOUBLE', 0);
define('HDOM_QUOTE_SINGLE', 1);
define('HDOM_QUOTE_NO',     3);
define('HDOM_INFO_BEGIN',   0);
define('HDOM_INFO_END',     1);
define('HDOM_INFO_QUOTE',   2);
define('HDOM_INFO_SPACE',   3);
define('HDOM_INFO_TEXT',    4);
define('HDOM_INFO_INNER',   5);
define('HDOM_INFO_OUTER',   6);
define('HDOM_INFO_ENDSPACE',7);
define('DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET', 'UTF-8');
define('DEFAULT_BR_TEXT', "\r\n");
define('DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT', " ");
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 600000);
// helper functions
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// get html dom from file
// $maxlen is defined in the code as PHP_STREAM_COPY_ALL which is defined as -1.
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
    //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

EDIT

It turns out that the error occurred in the `foreach` line, calling a method of an empty `array`. A neat and elegant way to do this `foreach` would be to define a helper `function`:

```
function myFind($input, $what) {
    if (!is_array($input)) {
        return $input->find($what);
    }
    $result = [];
    foreach ($input as $element) {
        $found = $element->find($what);
        foreach ($found as $f) $result[]=$f;
    }
    return $result;
}

and then call this like:

foreach(myFind($table, 'tr[class=portlet-table-alternate]') as $row) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment :], an error is line 20, which contains this part of code 

 `foreach($table->find('tr[class=portlet-table-alternate]') as $row) {`

But result of `$table = $html->find('table')` is an empty array.

Comment: @SebastianRygl thanks for pointing that out, indeed, my answer assumed that the error occurred in a different line from where it actually occurred. I will edit my answer with further information.

Comment: It's working perfectly, thank you, but still I can't figure it out, why an array is empty, because I know there is not an empty table on website :DD

Comment: @SebastianRygl that's strange indeed. Are you able to successfully query anything else? Are the tables loading if you turn off Javascript? Why do you specify the second parameter (use_include_path) to be false?

Comment: No, the tables are not loading if I turn off javascript :/

Comment: @SebastianRygl you are running a GET request and the Javascript is not executed, so this is the reason you do not see a table. You will need to take a look into the list of requests sent out by the page where the data needed to be loaded for the tables is being requested and send your requests there.